# ROM Upgrade From M to N with Internal Storage & Apps Migration Incl. Safe Backup with Internal Storage

Tags: rom-flashing, oneplus-3

Am running Resurrection ROM (M) on one Plus 3 (*this phone has only internal storage*).

Now How to upgrade ROM to Nuagot and still have all apps intact with its data on internal storage safely (*safely includes how to have backup with internal storage as TWRP does not copies internal storage :( *)

Comment: Use Titanium backup to backup your apps and data

Comment: Copied entire internal storage using TWRP and USB cable to Desktop along with TWRP backup. Thus provided full safety. TitaniumBackup was not able to store to sdcard (some marshmallow issue) for which used 'Document Storage' option for TitaniumBackup resolution. Thanks for idea :)